# What are the Mobile Considerations for IdentityConnect

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, single-sign-on

I'd like to implement IdentityConnect to sync the ActiveDirectory users in our network to our Salesforce users. Are there any mobile considerations I should be aware of?

Comment: Are you syncing with the SF database or trying to run a SF1 app? If with the database, I wouldn't expect any issues as SF will handle that internally.

Comment: The goal is to run the SF1 app.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Active Directory is more about where network shares are located & their size than anything else (its been years for me with MS networking). Your users will connect directly to SF1 by authenticating with SF Servers directly or via OAuth. As long as they can do that, there should be no issue. Mobile devices connect thru a user's mobile provider. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct correlation. You want to think about how mobile apps will authenticate to your org, what credentials they're going to use and their user experience. This largely depends on the mobile app(s) and how you set up your SFDC org. In a vanilla, out of the box config, the user account will be synced from AD to SFDC and that's it as far as Identity Connect goes.